# Orthogonality condition for angular momentum eigenstates in the coupled and uncoupled basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, representation-theory

I've been studying the addition of angular momentum in quantum mechanics but I can't understand the orthogonality condition for the coupled and uncoupled basis.

I know they are related by the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients 
$$|j_{1}j_{2}jm\rangle = \sum_{j_{1}m_{1}j_{2}m_{2}}\langle j_{1}m_{1};j_{2}m_{2}|j_{1}j_{2}jm\rangle |j_{1}m_{1};j_{2}m_{2}\rangle\tag{1}$$

where $j_{1},j_{2},m_{1},m_{2}$ correspond to the quantum numbers of each of the angular momentum in the system.

But what does $$\langle j_{1}^{'}j_{2}^{'}j^{'}m^{'}|j_{1}j_{2}jm\rangle\tag{2}$$ gives?

I think the result should be something proportional to $$\delta_{j_{1}^{'}j_{1}}\delta_{m_{1}^{'}m_{1}}\delta_{j_{2}^{'}j_{2}}\delta_{m_{2}^{'}m_{2}}\tag{3}$$ 
in order to the operator $\hat{j}^{2}$ be diagonal in the coupled basis but I'm not sure about it.

It's this true? It's this the whole answer?

Comment: How are $j_1$ & $j_2$ supposed to be both external labels and summation labels on the same time in eq. (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to think about this is to shorten $ \vert j_1m_1\rangle\vert j_2m_2\rangle=\vert j_1m_1;j_2m_2\rangle$ and observe that the $\{\vert j_1m_1\rangle\vert j_2 m_2\rangle\}$ span your space of states, with
$$
\hat 1 = \sum_{m_1m_2} \vert j_1m_1; j_2m_2\rangle
\langle j_1m_1;j_2m_2\vert
$$
so that a state $\vert jm\rangle$ is just
$$
\vert jm\rangle=\sum_{m_1m_2} \vert j_1m_1; j_2m_2\rangle
\langle j_1m_1;j_2m_2\vert jm\rangle\, .
$$
This way, another state $\vert j'm'\rangle$ would still be expanded in terms of $\vert j_1m_1\rangle\vert j_2 m_2\rangle$ and $\langle j'm'\vert jm\rangle=\delta_{jj'}\delta_{mm'}$

If $\vert j'm'\rangle$ does not live in the space spanned by $\{\vert j_1m_1\rangle\vert j_2 m_2\rangle\}$  but in some other space
$\{\vert j'_1m'_1\rangle\vert j'_2 m'_2\rangle\}$ then indeed the fuller orthogonality relation is 
$$
\langle j'm'\vert jm\rangle=\delta_{jj'}\delta_{mm'}\delta_{j_1j'_1}
\delta_{j_2j'_2}\, .
$$

Comment: Ohh i can see. This was that i cant fully understand in some books. They give some explanation about it but it wasn't clear at all for me. 

Thank you for your answer.